# Can use of many flutter hive box lead to low performace?

Tags: database, flutter, performance, flutter-hive

I am trying to make a money management app in flutter using hive. So I need to save data of each day in a box. If I use one hive box for one day there will be many hive boxes day after day. I need to know is there any simple way of doing this or creating many boxes in hive may lead to low performance.
Thank you!

Comment: Nobody answers! But did you get a answer from anywhere else?